# wget append the .html extension to the font files, is is possible to disable that feature for font files?

Tags: web, fonts, download, wget

I'm trying to download the website with help of wget. I use the following wget options `-p -E --no-cache --no-cookies`. As the result I've got `subset-Akrobat-Bold.woff2.html` file instead of `subset-Akrobat-Bold.woff2`, for example. Is it possible to prevent the .html extention for font files?

Comment: Addition to the question: As I see now, that problem heppens only for .woff2 type of fonts. The other types like .woff, .ttf are downloaded with the proper extension.